# Cocoon has_many polymorphic association not sending form values in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

I'm having a strange issue with [`Cocoon gem`](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), whenever I add new fields by Cocoon those fields are not send in params hash.

Regular fields, ones which are not build from the cocoon works as expected. Here's the relevant code.

```
class Standard < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :spaces, as: :space_sourceable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :spaces, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Space < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :space_sourceable, polymorphic: true
end

class ContractsController < ApplicationController

  def create
     set_resource(resource_class.new resource_params)
     if get_resource.save
       redirect_to authenticated_root_url, notice: "Contract successfully created."
     else
       render "new"
     end
  end

  def new
    set_resource(resource_class.new)
    build_nested_resources
  end

  private

  def build_nested_resources
    resource.spaces.build
  end

  def get_resource
    instance_variable_get("@#{resource_name}")
  end

  def set_resource(resource = nil)
    resource ||= resource_class.find_by_id params[:id]
    instance_variable_set("@#{resource_name}", resource)
    failure unless resource
  end

  def resource_name
    @resource_name ||= self.controller_name.singularize
  end

  def resource_class
    @resource_class ||= resource_name.classify.constantize
  end

  def resource_params
    params.require(resource_name.to_sym).permit(:id, :name, :note, spaces_attributes: [:id, :unit, :building, :floor, :amendment_type, :area, :space_sourceable_type, :space_sourceable_id, :_destroy]
  end
end

class StandardsController < ContractsController
end

#_form.html.haml
= form_for resource do |f|
  - if resource.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2 
        = pluralize(resource.errors.count, "error") 
            prohibited this lease information from being saved:
      %ul
        - resource.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg 
      .field
        %strong.upper Name:  
        = f.text_field :name, class: "input", style: "width: 450px;", required: true
        %h3.center-heading Space
        = render partial: "spaces", locals: {f: f}

#_spaces.html.haml
= f.fields_for :spaces do |space|
  = render "space_fields", f: space
.links
  = link_to_add_association 'Add Space', f, :spaces, partial: "space_fields"

#_space_fields.html.haml
.nested-fields
  .field
    .upper Unit  
    = f.text_field :unit, class: "input", style: "width: 450px;"
  .field
    .upper Building
    = f.text_field :building, class: "input", style: "width: 450px;"
  .field
    .upper Floor
    = f.text_field :floor, class: "input", style: "width: 450px;"
  .field
    .upper Area
    = f.text_field :area, class: "input", style: "width: 450px;"
  .field
    .upper Amendment Type
    = f.text_field :amendment_type, class: "input", style: "width: 450px;"
      = link_to_remove_association "Remove this Space", f
```

HTML generated by Cocoon and normal form fields looks good as well

```
#normal field from form
<input type="text" id="standard_spaces_attributes_0_unit" name="standard[spaces_attributes][0][unit]" class="input">

#field generated by cocoon
<input type="text" id="standard_spaces_attributes_1436417485840_unit" name="standard[spaces_attributes][1436417485840][unit]" class="input">
```

This is sending following parameters to server

```
{"standard"=>{"name"=>"fdfdfd", "spaces_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"unit"=>"asds", "building"=>"", "floor"=>"", "area"=>"", "amendment_type"=>""}}, "note"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Standard", "utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MYAn/MTgEOpS5B0xubsmMEW53EbOSPkgvJ/1sWTJAVcIf8cZLMNI6O1Py3qBho4Kkgteq5smJyYBNH1GT26Bqw==", "controller"=>"standards", "action"=>"create"}
```

P.S *set_resource and get_resource or any other generic methods work as expected as I'm able to save values under normal circumstances. I'm also able to add and remove fields by cocoon, it's just that those fields are not being sent along with other form attributes. It's not a strong parameters issue as well because values will get whitelisted only if they are actually present in params hash.*

Comment: Can you post your relevant `new` method of your controller?

Comment: @Pavan I was trying to avoid writing all the code as that part works fine. Anyways I have included it

Comment: Its ok. Are you getting the correct `resource` in `build_nested_resources`?

Comment: @Pavan Yes I'm, it shows up in params hash and gets saved in db as well. Only the fields generated by cocoon are not being sent in params

Comment: Bit confused. What are the fields generated by cocoon?

Comment: @Pavan All the fields present in space_fields partial. By Cocoon you can dynamically build and add another instace of nested resource. Checkout [`gems page`](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) for details.

Comment: So when you click on `Add Space` the new fields are not sent in params right?

Comment: @Pavan When I click on Add Spaces, it build another instance of space model, generates HTML for it from space_fields partial and append it to the form. I have even attached a sample HTML code for a particular input field and it looks good to me. The issue is that the data filled in fields generated by cocoon is not sent in params hash whereas I can see data from normal fields.